# How can I empty a Gtk.Window and then add new widgets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, pygtk

When clicking on a `Gtk.Button`, I want to remove all widgets from a `Gtk.Window` and then add new ones. However, new widgets never appear.

For example, in the following code, the "Success!" label never appears:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class FirstWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Test")
        self.mainBox = Gtk.Box(spacing=20, orientation="vertical")
        self.add(self.mainBox)

        self.labelTest = Gtk.Label(label="labelTest")
        self.mainBox.add(self.labelTest)

        self.btnNext = Gtk.Button(label="Next")
        self.btnNext.connect("clicked", self.on_btnNext_clicked)
        self.mainBox.pack_start(self.btnNext, False, False, 0)

    def on_btnNext_clicked(self, widget):
        self.remove(self.mainBox)
        self.redraw()

    def redraw(self):
        self.mainBox = Gtk.Box(spacing=20, orientation="vertical")
        self.add(self.mainBox)

        self.labelTest = Gtk.Label(label="Success!")
        self.mainBox.pack_start(self.labelTest, False, False, 0)

FirstWindow = FirstWindow()
FirstWindow.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
FirstWindow.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Why are you passing 'self' to redraw? Have you tried changing the size of the window after clicking next? It seems like you might be missing something to update the layout, similar to the self.mainBox.pack_start. https://athenajc.gitbooks.io/python-gtk-3-api/content/gtk-group/gtkbox.html#packstart the docs seem to recommend using that for adding widgets.

Comment: @matt You are right, `self` in `redraw()` was useless. Also, I replaced `mainBox.add()` by `mainBox.pack_start()` as suggested (but I really don't know one is preferred over the other, see [this doc](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBox.html#GtkBox.description)). It still does not work.